# Как правильно использовать "ленивую" регулярку

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Десериализовать пока не хочу. Использую след. регулярку. 
`(?<={)[\w\W]+?(?=},)`, но текст она выделяет промежутками

```
   {  
   "response":{  
      "count":6051,
      "items":[  
         {  
            "id":59801043,
            "from_id":-10639516,
            "owner_id":-10639516,
            "date":1440237924,
            "post_type":"post",
            "text":"",
            "is_pinned":1,
            "attachments":[  ],
            "comments":{  
               "count":828
            },
            "likes":{  
               "count":49105
            },
            "reposts":{  
               "count":2524
            }
         },
         {  
            "id":59853038,
            "from_id":-10639516,
            "owner_id":-10639516,
            "date":1440347764,
            "post_type":"post",
            "text":"Оболтусы, как выхи провели?",
            "comments":{  
               "count":568
            },
            "likes":{  
               "count":759
            },
            "reposts":{  
               "count":4
            }
         },
         {  
            "id":59852475,
            "from_id":-10639516,
            "owner_id":-10639516,
            "date":1440346226,
            "post_type":"post",
            "text":"",
            "attachments":[  
               {  
                  "type":"photo",
                  "photo":{  
                     "id":383043984,
                     "album_id":-7,
                     "owner_id":-10639516,
                     "user_id":100,
                     "photo_75":"http:\/\/cs7054.vk.me\/c7008\/v7008726\/309e7\/UZKjxTxeP_k.jpg",
                     "photo_130":"http:\/\/cs7054.vk.me\/c7008\/v7008726\/309e8\/EbAdPQzYlP0.jpg",
                     "photo_604":"http:\/\/cs7054.vk.me\/c7008\/v7008726\/309e9\/RERRhYNEfuU.jpg",
                     "width":500,
                     "height":300,
                     "text":"",
                     "date":1440346427,
                     "access_key":"9807ef378a904d1c99"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "comments":{  
               "count":113
            },
            "likes":{  
               "count":5964
            },
            "reposts":{  
               "count":267
            }
         },
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему вы не хотите использовать настоящий, нормальный парсер? Вы создаёте сами себе проблемы.

Comment: У меня есть проблема - думает программист - но я знаю регулярные выражения! Теперь у него две проблемы.

Comment: За последние два дня это уже 3-й(?) вопрос, где рекурсивную структуру пытаются «парсить» регулярками. Где-то прорвало?

Answer (score 2):

Ваше регулярное выражение ищет минимальное вхождение любого символа между `{` и `},` , но это не то, что Вам нужно.
Минимальная (ленивая) квантификация тут ни при чем.

Два пути решения: использовать особенность текста, что он выровнен отступами:

```
(?:\n|^)([ ]*)\{(.*?)\n\1\}
```

Либо использовать рекурсию для поиска сбалансированных фигурных скобок.
Не практикую С#, поэтому рекурсивное регулярное выражение не подскажу.